# Trying to decrement my static count variable in java jdk 1.8.0

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection, finalize

Using finalize function, when I point an object to `null` it’s not decrementing although it is incrementing properly. I also mentioned garbage collector which will listen to its own self, I know but why it’s not working. I am using java jdk 1.8.0.

```
public class student{
    private String name; private int roll; private static int count = 0;
    //setters
    public void setname(String nam){
        name = nam;
    }
    public void setroll(int rol){
        roll = rol;
    }
    //getters 
    public String getname(){
        return name;
    } 
    public int getroll(){
        return roll;
    }
    public static int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    //default constructor
    public student(){
        name = "default";
        roll = 9999;
        count += 1;
    }
    //parameterized constructor
    public student(String nam, int rol){
        setname(nam); setroll(rol);
        count += 1;
    }
    //copy constructor
    public student(student s){
        name = s.name; roll = s.roll;
        count += 1;
    }
    //methods to print on console
      public void print(){
    System.out.println("name: " + name + "\n" + "Roll Num: " + roll);
      }
     // overriding finalize method of Object class
     public void finalize(){
         count -= 1;
     }
}

//main function

public class clsnew{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("nuber of students" + student.getCount());
        student s1 = new student("Ahmad", 170404873); 
        student s2 = new student();
            s1.print(); //printing using parameterized constructor
            s2.print(); //printing using default constructor
            System.out.println("number of students" + student.getCount());

            s2.setname("Ali"); s2.setroll(200404230);

        System.out.print("s2: Name = "+s2.getname());
        System.out.println("Roll number: "+s2.getroll());

        student s3 = new student(s2);

        s2.print(); s3.print();
            System.out.println("number of students" + student.getCount());

        s2 = null;
        System.gc();

        int c = student.getCount();

            System.out.println("number of students" + student.getCount());

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? For what reason do you want to override ```finalize```?

Comment: `System.gc();` does not guarantee garbage collection will run, in fact given this short program it probably doesn't. To save time, there is no way to force garbage collection to run. And `finalize` is **deprecated**. And class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: *A static member is referenced by a class while the class is referenced by its class loader*  Unless the classloader unloads the class it will remain

Comment: i want to override finalize in order to see decrement in my student count variable when one of the object is not pointed by any variable.

Comment: public void finalize(){
         count -= 1;
     }

Comment: what is meant by deprecated

Comment: yes it is convention of class name that it should start with cap. but please tell me about my problem with not being able to decrement it. do i need to delete object if so than how? when will the object be destroyed and how would i use it to decrement my count var.

Comment: *"when one of the object is not pointed by any variable"*, but why? What is your motivation behind that? And please dont post 5 comments under each other. Just post one single comment.

Comment: *what is meant by deprecated* DANGER. Bridge is old and unsafe and scheduled for demolition. But if you ***want*** to drive across it, our engineer cannot legally stop you. If you continue past this point, you agree to hold us harmless.

Comment: @Nicktar why did you remove the `[garbage-collection]` tag?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never write applications relying on the garbage collector. Further, even if you need interaction with the garbage collector, you should avoid `finalize()`.

For educational purposes, you have to be aware of the following things:

- Finalization is not instantaneous. `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to identify a particular dead object, or even have an effect at all, but when it does, it may only enqueue the object for finalization, so by the time `System.gc()` returns, finalization might not have finished yet. It even might not have started yet.
- Since the finalizer runs in an arbitrary thread, it requires thread safe updates.

Make the following changes:

- Change `private static int count = 0;` to
  `private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();`,

  further `count += 1;` to `count.incrementAndGet();` in each constructor
  and `count -= 1;` to `count.decrementAndGet();` in the `finalize()` method.

  And `getCount()` to

  ```
    public static int getCount(){
        return count.get();
    }
  ```
- Change `System.gc();` to

  ```
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(100);
  ```

  You may surround the `sleep` call with a `try...catch` block or change the declaration of the `main` method adding `throws InterruptedException`

Then, you may observe the finalization of a `student` instance. To illustrate the counter-intuitive behavior of programs relying on garbage collection, I recommend running the program again, now with the `-Xcomp` option.

When you have JDK 11 or newer, you might also do a another run with
`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC`.